# Nginx shows 404, but vue-cli serves the route

Tags: vue.js, nginx

I have developed my app with vue-cli. It seems that it grabs any URL requests and Vue is able to process it. E.g. when I enter http://localhost:8080/prihlaseni in Chrome, the page is rendered.

I have recently tried to use Nginx to serve the content and do a reverse proxy for NodeJS backend. But this time this URL http://localhost/prihlaseni returns Nginx error 404. How can I fix it to vue handle this URL?

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        root   C:\dev\mezinamiridici\spa\dist;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure nginX to catch all non-existent paths and rewrite them to `index.html`

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
        root   C:\dev\mezinamiridici\spa\dist;
    }


    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    }
        
    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html last;          
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will update your answer with root directive that makes it work.